# How to find the XPATH of an element dynamically in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am working on a project in selenium python that I can use to beat a game online (this is for fun only not money). I am seaching for a square that becomes active via a CSS class name, I then want to store that elements XPATH into a list.

Is it possible to find the xpath of the element in this situation?
I don't care if the method is convoluted I am happy to change things if I can get that xpath dynamically?

Here is a some sample code of how I am finding the element.

```
def findElement():
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'active'))
        )   
         
    except Exception as e:
        print(e);
        driver.quit();
```

I have tried to save a refernce of the element to a list and then interact with it later but due to class changes it is not possible.
I am really in need of the Xpath of the element if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For the given code the xpath could be

```
f'//{element.tag_name}[@class="active"]'
```

or

```
parent = element.find_element(By.XPATH, '..')
f'//{parent.tag_name}/{element.tag_name}[@class="active"]'
```

or even attempt to find an ancestor with and id

```
ancestor_w_id = element.find_element(By.XPATH, 'ancestor::*[@id]')
ele_id = ancestor_w_id.get_attribute("id")
print(f'//{ancestor_w_id.tag_name}[@id="{ele_id}"]//{element.tag_name}[@class="active"]')
```

Finding the precise xpath to an element could be not that simple so these are generic attempts.